# Undefined variable SESSION

Tags: apache, session, php, ini

I am using php $_SESSION like this

```
 $_SESSION['original_referrer_location']
```

but i keep getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/m/inc/referrer.php on line 3
```

so I added this to the top of my script

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_start();
```

and all is good.

Is there a way to turn on sessions for good because having to add this on top of any script that needs a session is kind of redundant....i went to php.ini but there are many calls that start with session...any ideas on what i need to change ...I am on ubuntu 10.10/php5 in case that matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

But i wouldn't recommend using it. For example you would like to store whole object in session, to do it you would need to include file with class declaration first, otherwise unserialized object will be of incomplete class.

Other way is to [auto-prepend](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.auto-prepend-file) file that sets some basic configuration and starts session

Answer (score 2):

Yes

[session.auto.start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

> **session.auto_start**  *boolean*  session.auto_start specifies whether the  session module starts a session automatically on request startup.
>    Defaults to 0 (disabled).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use sessions, remember to call session_start() before the HTML tag

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<body>
...
```